# Increasing execution time of asynchronous operations inside a promise

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await, database-performance

Following is a piece of code which I am using to fetch data from an external source and dump it into my database(MongoDB).

```
        const chunks = [];
        while (data.length) {
            chunks.push(data.splice(0, config.sync_chunk_size));
        }
       
        let i = 0;
        for (const chunk of chunks) {
            let bulk_sync = [];
            for (const edata of chunk) {
                const set_data = {};
                for (const sync_map of sync_maps) {
                    set_data[sync_map.field] = '';
                    for (const sf of sync_map.possible_sfs) {
                        if (edata[sf]) {
                            set_data[sync_map.field] = edata[sf];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(fixed_fields)) {
                    set_data[key] = value;
                }
                set_data.search_data = '';
                for (const sf of SYNC_MAP.search_fields) {
                    set_data.search_data += `${set_data[sf]} `;
                }
                bulk_sync.push({
                    updateOne: {
                        filter: {
                            id: edata.ID
                        },
                        update: {
                            $set: set_data
                        },
                        upsert: true
                    }
                });
            }
            console.time('Write time');
            await cronRepository.bulkWrite(sync_db, bulk_sync, { ordered: false });
            console.timeEnd('Write time');
            await sleep(config.sync_sleep_time);
```

This function is execution inside`.then()` of a promise which returns 102705 records. My overall approach is as follows

1. Form batches of records, splitting a big array to smaller array of arrays of fixed size.
2. Using MongoDB's `bulkWrite` query, perform an upsert in database.
3. Make the thread "sleep" so that it doesn't block other requests.

I have set a timer in the code and these are the execution times for line `await cronRepository.bulkWrite(sync_db, bulk_sync, { ordered: false });`

417.519ms, 925.616ms, 831.365ms, 1.123s, 1.253s, 1.588s, 1.635s, 2.332s, 2.717s, 3.145s, 3.309s, 4.049s, 4.597s, 5.025s, 5.757s, 6.854s, 8.309s, 33.463s, 4.442s, 5.338s .....

I have skipped some execution times, but there is a pattern readily visible, it starts with a small execution time and keeps increasing, and again decreases suddenly and the pattern repeats.

What is the cause of this behaviour? The increase in times can be attributed to the upsert operation, as it needs to check more no of records every time, but then it doesn't explain the drop in time. This was run on my local machine and the server was executing only this function and serving no other requests. Is this due to how node processes the event loop or is it something on the database? MongoDB is a single instance server.

Comment: I'd wager it's the server.